# Why are the control statements[if-else, while, for] commonly used in programming?

Tags: programming-languages

One simple question I've never been able to answer is, "why use 'for', 'while', and 'if' as control statements?"

Could someone please elucidate the rationale behind using the above mentioned control statements, that have been embraced by most, if not all, high-level languages. I believe this has something to do with automata theory, but I'm generally uncertain.

Comment: Because you often need to do things more than once, and only do things if some condition holds? That seems to be the completely obvious answer to the question I think you're asking. So have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: No, you seem to understand the question, but why am I using those control statements across different languages?

Can computation be simplified to, doing "things more than once, and only do things if some condition holds"?

Comment: You use them across different langauges because they're useful for programming, regardless of what language you're using. To a large extent, yes, computation can be simplified in the way you suggest: essentially, you can simulate a Turing machine using only a repeat loop (repeat... until I reach the halting state), conditionals (if I see this character in this state, do that) and reading/writing memory.

Comment: @XYZandMe Where do you see the difference between "only do things if some condition holds" and "if / else"? Where do you see the difference between "things more than once" and for / while / repeat loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From computability theory, we know that a programming language which only contains terminating programs (say, without loops and recursion) is strictly less powerful than a Turing machine (or any other Turing-complete programming languages).

So, if we want a programming language $P$ which is able to express, say, a Python interpreter, a JVM implementation, or even an interpreter for $P$ itself, we need a language having some sort of unbounded loop / recursion.

Technically, if we have a `while` loop, we no longer need `if`, since

```
if condition then cTrue else cFalse
```

is equivalent to

```
branchTaken = false
while condition and !branchTaken do
   cTrue
   branchTaken = true
while !condition and !branchTaken do
   cFalse
   branchTaken = true
```

where `branchTaken` is an otherwise unused boolean variable.
But this is terribly inconvenient to use in practice!
So, programming languages tend to include `if`, even if not strictly needed.

Now, about `while` (ans similar unbounded loops). We said that we need some construct for unbounded looping/recursion. Why `while`, then?

Well, recursion alone suffices, but it is not very convenient in imperative programming. Note that, by contrast, functional programming languages typically do not have any `while` loop, and only exploit recursion -- in functional programming, recursion is far more natural and convenient, especially if the language is pure (without side effects) and a WHILE loop would be pointless, since we can not mutate variables.

Most widespread imperative programming languages use `while` or similar loops. In principle, they could instead use `if`+`goto`, which have the same power. However, practice showed that `goto` often led to code which was very hard to read and modify. Dijkstra wrote his famous letter "GOTO considered harmful", advocating for using structured programming (`while` and friends) instead. One of the scientific motivations behind this, is that to properly reason about a `while` loop we need to think about a loop invariant. This is already quite hard, in general. In a `goto`-using program, we need an invariant for every label/line number which is being targeted by some `goto`. This is much harder, in general, since many `goto`s may point to the same label, so the invariant must take into account the multiple "incoming" points. A solution for this could be using `goto` in a more disciplined way, but if we do, we'll probably end up in using `while` (or another loop) under a different notation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks, I tried to rephrase. (If you think it's still misleading, please let me know.)